# Spring Jpa - Need for longer strings in already existing column without recreating the schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, flyway

I have been working with an entity e.g. `Foo` defined as

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    String name;

    String description;
    
    // etc...
}
```

And I have some data already persisted in the db.

Now there has come up the need for longer descriptions so I tried modifying

```
String description;
```

to

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
String description = "";
```

but the changes were not reflected in the actual schema. I know that jpa hibernate will not update these kind of changes even when having set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

So what I want is to keep the already existing records, but modify the column definition to allow to insert new records with longer `description` fields.

What is the best way to do that?

I have done some investigating and came up upon solutions like Flyway, but what exactly is the way in which I should use it? Add a migration script with the following command?

```
ALTER TABLE Foo MODIFY description TEXT;
```

And then should I also add the `@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")` in the Java class or not?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the underlying DB is MySQL? What type is the description field currently? Because after MySQL 5.0.3 the VARCHAR fields can have up to a character size of 65.535 same as TEXT. [VARCHAR vs TEXT](https://www.navicat.com/en/company/aboutus/blog/1308-choosing-between-varchar-and-text-in-mysql)
So you might not even need to change the type just the max length of the field. For this I would use Flyway, that would make sure that your database changes are applied at the same time your code changes take effect as well.

Comment: Yes I am using MySQL and the description field is currnetly varchar(255). Is there someway to get the max size of 65.535 as a constant?

Comment: I would not simply set it to the max, but rather based on the requirement have a limit. What is the business need, you can even look into LONGTEXT if you need really large strings to be stored. As described in the link below the max 65k bytes are a limit for all the columns, e.g. the row itself. So one field should not take all the space. Then you also need to account for the collation, UTF8MB4 can you 4 bytes per character. See this page for more info: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size